# How to generate constant values with generic math

Tags: c#, generics, .net-7.0, .net-generic-math

I have the following generic math function:

```cs
private static T Fade<T>(T t)
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);
}
```

This doesn't compile however, since `6`, `15` and `10` are not of type `T`.

The best solution I could come up with was to define a static class like this:

```cs
private static class GenericValues<T>
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    public static readonly T Two = T.One + T.One;
    public static readonly T Three = Two + T.One;
    public static readonly T Four = Three + T.One;
    public static readonly T Five = Four + T.One;

    public static readonly T Six = Five + T.One;
    public static readonly T Ten = Five * Two;
    public static readonly T Fifteen = Five * Three;
}
```

And then the function becomes this:

```cs
private static T Fade<T>(T t)
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    return t * t * t * (t * (t * GenericValues<T>.Six - GenericValues<T>.Fifteen) + GenericValues<T>.Ten);
}
```

This feels a bit like a hack though, is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use one of the `INumberBase<T>.CreateX` methods, for example [`INumberBase<TSelf>.CreateChecked<TOther>(TOther)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0) to convert the number literals to the generic number type:

```cs
private static T Fade<T>(T t)
    where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    return t * t * t * 
        (t * (t * T.CreateChecked(6) - T.CreateChecked(15)) + T.CreateChecked(10));
}
```

Comment: Given that I had to also do `T two = T.One + T.One` etc, this would make my life easier too. Never knew about `T.Create()` methods.