# Designing generic types with constraints on generic math interfaces

Tags: c#, floating-point, .net-generic-math

Consider the following trivial example, which is a struct that represents the square of an `ISignedNumber<T>`.

```cs
public readonly struct Square<T> where T : ISignedNumber<T>
{
    public Square(T value)
    {
        Value = value * value;
    }
    
    public T Value { get; }
}

Square<int> a = new(123);
Console.WriteLine(a.Value); // 15129

Square<long> b = new(1234567);
Console.WriteLine(b.Value); // 1524155677489

Square<BigInteger> c = new(BigInteger.Parse("123456789000000000"));
Console.WriteLine(c.Value); // 15241578750190521000000000000000000
```

Notably, this implementation will work for anything that implements `ISignedNumber<T>`, since `value * value` is possible.

Less trivial is how to build structs that require prior knowledge of known constants; for example, I might want to build a struct that represents the golden ratio of a given number, which requires knowledge of Phi

(phi): φ = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2 ≈ 1.61803398875

As this value is a constant literal, it cannot be applied `where T : IFloatingPoint<T>`.

```cs
public readonly struct GoldenRatio<T> where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    public static T Phi = 1.61803398875;
}
```

> Cannot convert source type 'double' to target type 'T'

Whilst I assume that the answer is simply that this isn't possible with generic math interfaces, I figured I would ask here anyway, in case there is something that I have overlooked.

The only thing I can think of is that when instances of `GoldenRatio<T>` are created, the values have to be passed in based on the selected type; i.e. `float`, `double`, `decimal`, but that ultimately restricts the type to only allow a finite set of `IFloatingPoint<T>` implementations, and at runtime, which isn't very nice.

Comment: Check out also [How to generate constant values with generic math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365299/how-to-generate-constant-values-with-generic-math) and [Using Numeric literals/constants in Generic Math C# 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75774497/using-numeric-literals-constants-in-generic-math-c-sharp-11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some creation [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0) you can use to convert from a float number.

```
public readonly struct GoldenRatio<T> where T : IFloatingPoint<T>
{
    public static readonly T Phi = T.CreateChecked(1.61803398875);
}
```